# Android phone bluetooth connection to two chips

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get my Android phone (NexusOne) to connect to two bluetooth chips simultaneously. I have read various responses on the internet concluding that this may or may not be able to be done. People who have gotten it working say it works by establishing multiple RFcomm connections, like two connect threads in parallel. I am not sure how to go about doing this. I have my connect code which will only connect to one chip at the moment. Ideas?

```
    package com.example.connect;
    public class ConnectThread extends Activity {
        static BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        static BluetoothSocket mmSocket2;
        static BluetoothDevice mmDevice;
        static BluetoothDevice mmDevice2;
        static InputStream mmInputStream;
        static OutputStream mmOutputStream;
        static BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
        static BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter2;
        TextView myLabel;


       @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_connect_thread);

        Button button = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        myLabel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(ConnectThread.this, "Connection in progress", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                myLabel.setText("Connection in progress");
                try 
                {
                     findBT2();
                     openBT2();
                     findBT();
                     openBT();
                }
                catch (IOException ex) { }
               }        
             });}




            void findBT2() 
            {


                mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
                if(mBluetoothAdapter == null)
                {
                    myLabel.setText("No bluetooth adapter available");
                }

                if(!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled())
                {
                    Intent enableBluetooth = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                    startActivityForResult(enableBluetooth, 0);
                }

                Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
                if(pairedDevices.size() > 0)
                {
                    for(BluetoothDevice device2 : pairedDevices)
                    {
                        if(device2.getName().equals("H-C-2010-06-01")) 
                        {
                            mmDevice2 = device2;
                            myLabel.setText("Bluetooth Device Found");
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if(pairedDevices.size()==0){myLabel.setText("Please Pair devices");}
                }




            }
            public int openBT2() throws IOException
            {
                UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"); //Standard SerialPortService ID
                mmSocket2 = mmDevice2.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);        
                mmSocket2.connect();
                mmOutputStream = mmSocket2.getOutputStream();
                mmInputStream = mmSocket2.getInputStream();

                return 1;
            }


             void findBT() 
            {


                mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
                if(mBluetoothAdapter == null)
                {
                    myLabel.setText("No bluetooth adapter available");
                }

                if(!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled())
                {
                    Intent enableBluetooth = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                    startActivityForResult(enableBluetooth, 0);
                }

                Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
                if(pairedDevices.size() > 0)
                {
                    for(BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices)
                    {
                        if(device.getName().equals("HC-05")) 
                        {
                            mmDevice = device;
                            myLabel.setText("Bluetooth Device Found");
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if(pairedDevices.size()==0){myLabel.setText("Please Pair devices");}
                }




            }

            public int openBT() throws IOException
            {
                UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"); //Standard SerialPortService ID
                mmSocket = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);        
                mmSocket.connect();
                mmOutputStream = mmSocket.getOutputStream();
                mmInputStream = mmSocket.getInputStream();

                return 1;
            }

            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String action = intent.getAction();
                if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED.equals(action))
                { myLabel.setText("CONNECTED");}
            }
            void closeBT() throws IOException
        {

            mmOutputStream.close();
            mmInputStream.close();
            mmSocket.close();
            myLabel.setText("Bluetooth Closed");
        }
}
```

Comment: It must work, you only must connect all with the same UUID.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: I got a double connection by instead of trying to connect to each chip separately, just pulling up a list of paired devices and connecting to each one at a time. This worked to connect to both however still no data showing...
    public class Main_Activity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

```
ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter;
ListView listView;
static TextView MyLabel;
BluetoothAdapter btAdapter;
Set<BluetoothDevice> devicesArray;
ArrayList<String> pairedDevices;
ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> devices;
public static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
protected static final int SUCCESS_CONNECT = 0;
protected static final int MESSAGE_READ = 1;
IntentFilter filter;
BroadcastReceiver receiver;
String tag = "debugging";

Handler mHandler = new Handler(){
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i(tag, "in handler");
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        switch(msg.what){
        case SUCCESS_CONNECT:
            // DO something
            ConnectedThread connectedThread = new ConnectedThread((BluetoothSocket)msg.obj);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CONNECT", 0).show();
            String s = "successfully connected";
            connectedThread.write(s.getBytes());
            Log.i(tag, "connected");
            break;
        case MESSAGE_READ:
            byte[] readBuf = (byte[])msg.obj;
            String string = new String(readBuf);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), string, 0).show();
            MyLabel.setText(string);
            break;
        }
    }
};
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    MyLabel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Receive);
    init();
    if(btAdapter==null){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No bluetooth detected", 0).show();
        finish();
    }
    else{
        if(!btAdapter.isEnabled()){
            turnOnBT();
        }

        getPairedDevices();
        startDiscovery();
    }


}
private void startDiscovery() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
    btAdapter.startDiscovery();

}
private void turnOnBT() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent intent =new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}
private void getPairedDevices() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    devicesArray = btAdapter.getBondedDevices();
    if(devicesArray.size()>0){
        for(BluetoothDevice device:devicesArray){
            pairedDevices.add(device.getName());

        }
    }
}
private void init() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    listAdapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,0);
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    pairedDevices = new ArrayList<String>();
    filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    devices = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();
    receiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String action = intent.getAction();

            if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)){
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                devices.add(device);
                String s = "";
                for(int a = 0; a < pairedDevices.size(); a++){
                    if(device.getName().equals(pairedDevices.get(a))){
                        //append 
                        s = "(Paired)";
                        break;
                    }
                }

                listAdapter.add(device.getName()+" "+s+" "+"\n"+device.getAddress());
            }

            else if(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED.equals(action)){
                // run some code
            }
            else if(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)){
                // run some code



            }
            else if(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED.equals(action)){
                if(btAdapter.getState() == btAdapter.STATE_OFF){
                    turnOnBT();
                }
            }

        }
    };

    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
     filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
     filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
     filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
}

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth must be enabled to continue", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
    }
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(btAdapter.isDiscovering()){
            btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        }
        if(listAdapter.getItem(arg2).contains("Paired")){

            BluetoothDevice selectedDevice = devices.get(arg2);
            ConnectThread connect = new ConnectThread(selectedDevice);
            connect.start();
            Log.i(tag, "in click listener");
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "device is not paired", 0).show();
        }
    }

    private class ConnectThread extends Thread {

        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

        public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
            // Use a temporary object that is later assigned to mmSocket,
            // because mmSocket is final
            BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
            mmDevice = device;
            Log.i(tag, "construct");
            // Get a BluetoothSocket to connect with the given BluetoothDevice
            try {
                // MY_UUID is the app's UUID string, also used by the server code
                tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
            } catch (IOException e) { 
                Log.i(tag, "get socket failed");

            }
            mmSocket = tmp;
        }

        public void run() {
            // Cancel discovery because it will slow down the connection
            btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
            Log.i(tag, "connect - run");
            try {
                // Connect the device through the socket. This will block
                // until it succeeds or throws an exception
                mmSocket.connect();
                Log.i(tag, "connect - succeeded");
            } catch (IOException connectException) {    Log.i(tag, "connect failed");
                // Unable to connect; close the socket and get out
                try {
                    mmSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException closeException) { }
                return;
            }

            // Do work to manage the connection (in a separate thread)

            mHandler.obtainMessage(SUCCESS_CONNECT, mmSocket).sendToTarget();
        }



        /** Will cancel an in-progress connection, and close the socket */
        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) { }
        }
    }

    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            mmSocket = socket;
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            // Get the input and output streams, using temp objects because
            // member streams are final
            try {
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) { }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }

        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(Main_Activity.this, "running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            byte[] buffer;  // buffer store for the stream
            int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

            // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
            while (true) {
                try {
                    // Read from the InputStream
                    buffer = new byte[5000];
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                    // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity
                    mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                            .sendToTarget();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        /* Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device */
        public void write(byte[] bytes) {
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(bytes);
            } catch (IOException e) { }
        }

        /* Call this from the main activity to shutdown the connection */
        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) { }
        }
    }
```

}